# How to set default card without any selection

Tags: kotlin, default-value, card

I am developing e-commerce app in which users can set multiple options for address. Which by default they have to select every time. Each address have a separate address id which helps in identification of address selected. To reduce extra click of users i want to make first address i.e. address id present on position 0 as default selected address. Different address are present in different material card view so you can easily select one of them. My app screen shot is present as below.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8qJ2l.jpg)

My code is as following

```
import android.content.Context
import android.util.Log
import android.util.TypedValue
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.ViewGroup
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
import com.sbhs.stone.R
import com.sbhs.stone.data.UserData
import com.sbhs.stone.databinding.LayoutAddressCardBinding
import com.sbhs.stone.ui.getCompleteAddress

private const val TAG = "AddressAdapter"

class AddressAdapter(
    private val context: Context,
    addresses: List<UserData.Address>,
    private val isSelect: Boolean,
) :
    RecyclerView.Adapter<AddressAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

    lateinit var onClickListener: OnClickListener
    var data: List<UserData.Address> = addresses

    var lastCheckedAddress: String? = null
    private var lastCheckedCard: MaterialCardView? = null
    var selectedAddressPos = -1


    inner class ViewHolder(private var binding: LayoutAddressCardBinding) :
        RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {
        fun bind(address: UserData.Address, position: Int) {
            binding.addressCard.isChecked = position == selectedAddressPos
            binding.addressPersonNameTv.text =
                context.getString(R.string.person_name, address.fName, address.lName)
            binding.addressCompleteAddressTv.text = getCompleteAddress(address)
            binding.addressMobileTv.text = address.phoneNumber
            if (isSelect) {
                binding.addressCard.setOnClickListener {
                    onCardClick(position, address.addressId, it as MaterialCardView)
                }
            }
            //binding.addressCard.setOnFocusChangeListener { view: View, b: Boolean ->
            //  onCardClick(0, address.addressId, 0 as MaterialCardView)
            //}
            binding.addressEditBtn.setOnClickListener {
                onClickListener.onEditClick(address.addressId)
            }
            binding.addressDeleteBtn.setOnClickListener {
                onClickListener.onDeleteClick(address.addressId)
                notifyDataSetChanged()
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        return ViewHolder(
            LayoutAddressCardBinding.inflate(
                LayoutInflater.from(parent.context),
                parent,
                false
            )
        )
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.bind(data[position], position)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int = data.size

    interface OnClickListener {
        fun onEditClick(addressId: String)
        fun onDeleteClick(addressId: String)
    }

    private fun onCardClick(position: Int, addressTd: String, card: MaterialCardView) {
        if (addressTd != lastCheckedAddress) {
            card.apply {
                strokeColor = context.getColor(R.color.blue_accent_300)
                isChecked = true
                strokeWidth = TypedValue.applyDimension(
                    TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP,
                    2F,
                    resources.displayMetrics
                ).toInt()
            }
            lastCheckedCard?.apply {
                strokeColor = context.getColor(R.color.light_gray)
                isChecked = false
                strokeWidth = TypedValue.applyDimension(
                    TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP,
                    1F,
                    resources.displayMetrics
                ).toInt()
            }

            lastCheckedAddress = addressTd
            lastCheckedCard = card
            selectedAddressPos = position
            Log.d(TAG, "onCardClick: selected address = $addressTd")
        }
    }
}
```

So in above code i want to make selectedAddressPos = 0, & last checked Address as addressTd of address present on position 0. Remember my address can be null so this condition should only applied when address is non-null. Please help me i am new in coding. The information about user address are stored in firebase. so i cant make any card as default from xml.

I tried to make selectedAddressPos as 0 at time of initiation but it will only show it in app and no address id is taken.